# Type error for not enough arguments when 2 arugments are already passed

Tags: python

I am getting the following error,it says not enough arguments,am already passing two arguments...what is wrong here?

```
   check_call("rm -rf %s/%s/*" % SCRIPT_ROOT % W_ROOT,shell=True)                                
    TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do the formatting in two steps like that.  You need to use one `%` operator and pass a tuple:

```
"rm -rf %s/%s/*" % (SCRIPT_ROOT, W_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 2):

`check_call('rm -rf {}/{}/*'.format(SCRIPT_ROOT,W_ROOT),shell=True)`

Also, make sure you know the implications of `shell=True`, especially since you seem to be doing a destructive operation.

What happenes if any one of the arguments is `../../`?